# Indexes of disjoint sets

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Let's call an index of a set $A$ a function $$I_A(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\quad x \notin A\\ 1 &\quad x \in A \end{cases}$$

Now, suppose $A$ and $B$ are two disjoint sets. Is it always true that $I_A + I_B = I_{A \cup B}$?

I know, that for any two arbitrary sets $A$ and $B$ we have:

$$I_{A \cup B} = \max(I_A, I_B)$$
$$I_{A \cap B} = \min(I_A, I_B)$$

but I do not know how to go on from here...

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with *learning*, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: Don't expect us to prove it for you. Please read through [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and come back with your attempts.

Comment: How do you mean 'index set' here? Are you sure it's not rather about the *cardinals* of the given sets?

Comment: @Berci I suspect that it concerns "indicator function".

Comment: Have you tried it for a few small finite specific examples in order to understand what's going on? No point in trying to write a general proof until you see why it's true, which (IMO) is often easier with specific examples. E.g. let A = {2,3,5,6} and B = {1,8} subsets of {1, 2, ..., 10}. Write down the index functions of A, B and their union as charts. Does it work? Can you see why?

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, I assume, that by "index set" you mean set index - a function $$I_A(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\quad x \notin A\\ 1 &\quad x \in A \end{cases}$$

Yes it is. If $x \in A$ and $x \notin B$, then $I_A(x) = 1$, $I_B(x) = 0$ and $I_{A\cup B}(x) = 1 = 0 + 1 = I_A(x) + I_B(x)$. If $x \notin A$ and $x \in B$, then $I_A(x) = 0$, $I_B(x) = 1$ and $I_{A\cup B}(x) = 1 = 0 + 1 = I_A(x) + I_B(x)$. If $x \notin A$ and $x \notin B$, then $I_A(x) = 0$, $I_B(x) = 0$ and $I_{A\cup B}(x) = 0 = 0 + 0 = I_A(x) + I_B(x)$. No other cases are possible, because the sets are disjoint.